# Macros expanding to addhook

Tags: hooks, elisp-macros, defmacro

I have the following configuration lines in my `init.el` file regarding a specific mode:

```
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "SPC h") #'evil-window-left)))
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "SPC l") #'evil-window-right)))
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "SPC k") #'evil-window-up)))
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "SPC j") #'evil-window-down)))
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "SPC") #'nil)))
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "j") 'pdf-view-next-line-or-next-page)))
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "k") 'pdf-view-previous-line-or-previous-page)))
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "4") 'pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation)))
```

I thought to myself: "Hey this is a good place to use a macro!".
What I want to do is to be able to type

```
(pdf-binding "something" function)
```

And that it expands to

```
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "something") #'function)))
```

Very similar to C's macros, the simple "text replacement" stuff.

So I tried the following:

```
(defmacro pdf-binding (key function)
  (add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd key) function))))
```

But when I tried using it like in the example above, I get the following error:

`Symbol's value as variable is void: pdf-tools-enable-minor-modes`

I tried using " `", doing`(list add-hook ...)`. But nothing works.

How could I achieve it? What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a Lisp macro behave?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78347/how-does-a-lisp-macro-behave)

Comment: Don't use lambdas as hook functions - makes it hard to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding eight anonymous functions to the hook makes no sense to me, vs this:

```el
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook #'my-pdf-view-mode-config)

(defun my-pdf-view-mode-config ()
  "Called via `pdf-view-mode-hook'."
  (local-set-key (kbd "SPC") nil)
  (local-set-key (kbd "SPC h") #'evil-window-left)
  (local-set-key (kbd "SPC l") #'evil-window-right)
  (local-set-key (kbd "SPC k") #'evil-window-up)
  (local-set-key (kbd "SPC j") #'evil-window-down)
  (local-set-key (kbd "j") #'pdf-view-next-line-or-next-page)
  (local-set-key (kbd "k") #'pdf-view-previous-line-or-previous-page)
  (local-set-key (kbd "4") #'pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation))
```

or a one-time evaluation:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "pdf-view"
  (my-pdf-view-config))

(defun my-pdf-view-config ()
  "Called after loading pdf-view.el."
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "SPC h") #'evil-window-left)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "SPC l") #'evil-window-right)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "SPC k") #'evil-window-up)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "SPC j") #'evil-window-down)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "j") #'pdf-view-next-line-or-next-page)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "k") #'pdf-view-previous-line-or-previous-page)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "4") #'pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation))
```

You could iterate over a list of `(KEY . COMMAND)` pairs if you wanted to reduce the amount of text.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "pdf-view"
  (my-pdf-view-config))

(defun my-pdf-view-config ()
  "Called after loading pdf-view.el."
  (dolist (keybind '(("SPC" . nil)
                     ("SPC h" . evil-window-left)
                     ("SPC l" . evil-window-right)
                     ("SPC k" . evil-window-up)
                     ("SPC j" . evil-window-down)
                     ("j" . pdf-view-next-line-or-next-page)
                     ("k" . pdf-view-previous-line-or-previous-page)
                     ("4" . pdf-annot-add-highlight-markup-annotation)))
    (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd (car keybind)) (cdr keybind))))
```